# Build an application with Truffle + React + Redux

Tags: truffle, uport, react, truffle-box

I'm looking for some examples about how to build a Dapp with Truffle + React + Redux.

I'm able to only find this old tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GPP6uAq15d8.

Does anyone have some other material? GitHub repo, guides.

Thank's a lot.

**Working "like" a boilerplate**

https://github.com/ConsenSys/Token-Factory

**20/03/17 Update**
Very cool https://truffle-box.github.io/

Comment: This might help a little: https://github.com/niran/dapp-boilerplate

Comment: I will try later, It sounds great : )

Answer (score 2):

DevCon2 helped me :) 
React Boilerplate https://github.com/silentcicero/react-dapp-boilerplate

Answer (score 2):

You can use [truffle-box](https://github.com/truffle-box/truffle-box-auth)

It does not come with a reducer for web3, which will be helpful if you are looking to support browser based wallets.

Here's a [fork with a web3 reducer](https://github.com/qjflores/truffle-box-browser-wallet) that let's you pass web3 to components as a prop

Comment: Today I'm working on what you did in your fork. Thank you.

Comment: Hi man, Instead of a reducer, I prefer a wrapper like this one http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/12840/undefined-in-truffle-contract-initialization/12850#12850

Answer (score 0):

I've just come across this tutorial: https://github.com/davidoevans/react-dapp

It uses Reflux rather than Redux but as it takes you through constructing the boilerplate step by step that shouldn't be too hard to change out. You could use any React starter template instead.

There is a webpack tutorial here: http://truffleframework.com/tutorials/bundling-with-webpack

Comment: Actually I use this like boilerplate https://github.com/ConsenSys/Token-Factory

Comment: That's cool, sorry I was just trying to help.